# TreeMap to Array. Does the array keep the order?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, treemap

For every time, if I put the same values to the treeMap, the order of data in treeMap will be the same, right? No matter VM etc? I want to find out, if I convert treeMap to array on following way, I get sorted array, for every time in the same order for fixed treeMap.

```
 Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
 treeMap.put("a","1");
 ...
 treeMap.put("zzz","1000");
 String[] myArray = treeMap.values().toArray(new String[treeMap.values().size()]);
```

If I execute above code I always receive the same value of myArray [100]? I assume that all keys are different.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#values()) is documented as "in ascending order of the corresponding keys."

[`Collection.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) is documented as returning elements in iteration order, since there are ordering guarantees on the collection.